# Jquery add option to all select elements with 2D names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to dynamically add an option value to ALL select fields with a certain multidimensional name, but I just can't seem to figure it out :(

**Here is the HTML :**

```
<input type="text" name="computer['id'][]" onBlur="load_comp_select();">
```

Dynamically added service input field.  There can be over 10 indexes.

```
<select name="service['comp_id'][]">
</select>
```

**Here is the JS :**

```
function load_comp_select(){
    var computers = $("input[name^='computer[\\'id\\']']").serializeArray();
    $.each(computers, function(i, field){
        console.log(field.value);
        $.each($("input[name^='service[\\'comp_id\\'][]']"), function(key, value){
            console.log("service : " + key);
            $("input[name^='service[\\'comp_id\\']']").eq(key).append($('<option/>', {
                                                            value: field.value,
                                                            text : field.value
                                                            }));
        });
    });
}
```

To sum up what I am attempting to do...  When I type in a computer ID in any of the computer['id'][] fields, the value of that field with be added as an option to all selects with the name service['comp_id'].  Any help is appreciated!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqvsabzq/3/)

Comment: can you share a fiddle of your example?

Comment: Also have use `computer.id` and `service.comp_id` in the names of the elements so it can be accessed like `$("input[name=computer.id]")` and `$("select[name=service.comp_id]")` respectively. Otherwise, @Iqbal Pasha 's answer is perfect

Comment: JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xqvsabzq/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this below code it may help you to add select options dynamically.

```js
$(".ip1").blur(function () {
  var opt = $("#ip1").val();
  var defaultText = '';
  $('#List').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", opt).text(opt));
  $(this).val(defaultText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="ip1" class="ip1" name="computer['id'][]" />
<select id="List" name="service['comp_id'][]"></select>
```

Comment: This worked actually for the first select, but any service dynamically added after that, it would leave them blank.